# Why this function is not surjective?: $f(x) = 1/(-x+1)$

Tags: functions

Why this function is not surjective? $f(x) = 1/(-x+1)$

The domain is R \ {1} and codomain is R \ {0}. If I understand it properly, it is not surjective, because H(f) does not equal to R \ {1}.

Comment: What is $Hf{}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: What is $H(f)$?

Comment: H(f) = The output values of the function if we give all the domain numbers to it.. In English the range of function I guess..

Comment: Every function is surjective onto its image. What is the codomain you are considering? Without that, your question is meaningless. Having said that, note that $0\notin \text{im}(f)$ whatever to codomain might be.

Answer (score 2):

If your codomain is also $\mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$ the $0$ is not in the range of $f$, so $f$ is not surjective.

If the codomain is $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ then $f$ is surjective.

Comment: My codomain is R \ {0} and domain is R \ {1}. Why than this function is not surjective?

Comment: You said that $H(f)\neq \mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$, so $f$ is not sirjective. Are you changing the question now?

Comment: That is what I meant. So function would be surjective only if H(f) would equal to domain right?

Comment: No. $f$ is surjective if $H(f)$ is equal to the codomain.

Comment: Actually they did not specify the domain neither the codomain. They have just asked in my school if this function is surjective.. But when they do not specify domain, we suppose it is the biggest possible in real numbers, so R \ {1}.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the codomain 
If codomain includes zero then the function $$f(x) = 1/(-x+1)$$ is not surjective because it does not cover $y=0$ because $$\frac {1}{-x+1}=0$$ does not have a solution.

Note that for a fraction to be equal $0$ w have to have the numerator equal zero while the denominator is not zero.

On the other hand if codomain does not include zero the function is surjective.

Comment: and x=1 is undefined.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee correct but the question is about surjectivity which relates to the range not the domain of the function.

Comment: Note that the question now includes $\mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ as codomain. The function is surjective after all! Like I mentioned immediately in the comments, the question is absolutely meaningless without first specifying the codomain! Don't answer these questions with an assumption in mind that seems obvious, it is not obvious to the one asking.

Comment: Very good point. One needs to pay attention to details before jumping at conclusions